# X[Y|Z] formulas

Tags: ionic-compounds, notation

I often find formulas of minerals where some element symbols are grouped within square brackets and separated by a vertical bar. An example can be brochantite, whose formula I find expressed as $\ce{Cu_4[(OH)_6|SO_4]}$.

I wonder what does such a notation means, and I have made some conjectures, although I find no reference on line or in books. I suppose that the square brackets are used to enclose the set of the anions present in the compound and the vertical bar is used to separates different anions, while the cations remain outside the square brackets. That is just an intuitive supposition. Is my supposition correct? If it is not, what does the described notation mean?

Comment: I'm not sure but wikipedia has just written a *normal* formula for Brochantite:  $\ce{Cu4SO4(OH)6}$. Could you give me some reference of where you saw that formula?

Comment: @MARamezani Thank you very much for the comment! I've found this particular formula in an Italian language book: A. Mottana, R. Crespi, G. Liborio, "Minerali e rocce" ('Minerals and rocks'), but I've found similar notations in several other books of earth sciences.

Comment: Maybe, *and I say maybe*, they wanted to demonstrate something like, for example, brochantite has $\ce{OH-}, \ce{SO4^{2-}}$ and copper.

Comment: @MARamezani Thank you again! I've just found other similar formulas in Mottana-Crespi-Liborio's text: Cu[UO$_2$|PO$_4$]$_2\cdot$12H$_2$O for torbernite, K$_2$[(UO$_2$)|V$_2$O$_8$]$\cdot$3H$_2$O for carnotite... but UO$_2$ is cation UO$_2^{2+}$, not an anion. Therefore my initial supposition that the brackets contain anions was wrong...

Comment: Now that I think about it, I see that two brackets like this ][, if not awkward, would've looked way messier than a | . Maybe it was the author's or the publisher's attempt to make chemical formulas look a little bit neater.

Comment: @Self-teachingDavide Since $UO$ exists as a compound, then $UO_2^{2-}$ can also exist. http://webelements.com/compounds/uranium/uranium_oxide.html

Answer (score 3):

[The IUPAC rules for punctuation marks](http://old.iupac.org/reports/provisional/abstract04/RB-prs310804/Chap2-3.04.pdf) in chemical formulas don't mention [|], so that notation must be peculiar to geology. They *need* different notation; chemists write  formulas for molecules, while geologists focus more on complicated superstructures built from smaller structures that can be arranged in different ways, even within the same superstructure.

[This paper](http://www.academia.edu/7540967/Brochantite_Cu4SO4_OH_6_OD_character_polytypism_and_crystal_structures) describes the structure of brochantite as layers and chains of copper(II) ions octahedrally coordinated with hydroxides. The octahedra in different layers and chains  are crosslinked by sulfate ions.

Perhaps the notation $\rm [(OH)_6|SO_4]$ is an attempt to indicate this arrangement. The brackets denote the electronegative part of the structure, with what comes before the vertical bar representing directly coordinated ions, with what comes  after representing ions that aren't directly coordinated.

I'm speculating, though. Sorry. I would have put this into a comment, but it's too long and I wanted to give you the links to think about.